# How to untar all tar files in current directory using Putty

Tags: bash, tar

How can I untar all tar files in one command using Putty.

I Tried the following but its not un-tarring (all files start with alcatelS*)

```
 tar -xfv alcatelS*.tar
```

It is not working i don't get no errors and it is not un-tarring.
Thank you,

Comment: What does `echo  tar -xfv alcatelS*.tar` say?

Comment: it displays tar -xfv and all the tar files

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`-xfv` is wrong since `v` is being referred as the file instead. Also, `tar` can't accept multiple files to extract at once. Perhaps `-M` can be used but it's a little stubborn when I tried it. Also, it would be difficult to pass multiple arguments that were extracted from pathname expansion i.e. you have to do `tar -xvM -f file1.tar -f file2.tar`.

Do this instead:

```
for F in alcatelS*.tar; do
    tar -xvf "$F" 
done
```

Or one-line: *(EDIT: Sorry that -is- a "one"-liner but I find that not technically a real one-liner, just a condensed one so I should haven't referred to that as a one-liner.  Avoid the wrong convention.)*

```
for F in alcatelS*.tar; do tar -xvf "$F"; done
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use  following command for extract all tar.gz files in directory in unix

```
find . -name 'alcatelS*.tar.gz' -exec tar -xvf {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is my favorite way to untar multiple tar files:

```
ls *tar.gz | xargs -n1 tar xvf
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in one line:

```
cat *.tar | tar -xvf - -i
```